# Can Elasticsearch mark (add some value to one of fields) all documents affected by search query?

Tags: database, elasticsearch, nosql

Data:

- I have N number of Elastic queries: query1, query2, query3, ...
- I have M number of documents in Elastic index: A, B, C, D, E, F, ...

Queries:

- When I run query1 it returns documents: A, D, E
- When I run query2 it returns documents: A, B, C, D
- When I run query3 it returns documents: A, D, E, F

And then I would like to create query (match_all: {}) which will return me:

- A - query1, query2, query3
- B - query1, query2
- C - query2
- D - query1, query3
- E - query1, query3
- F - query3

I know that I can run all N queries and then go one by one and update all documents (add flag that the documents is affected by the query X).

But there are two problems with this solution:

- This N queries can be modified so we will have size of data modification in worst case for each query (because I will then need to go for each document and update that it is affected by this query)
- The marking process would cost N*M in worst case

**Is there some way to tell Elastic to update all documents with some flag (add "query1" string to one of fields in documents") when documents is returned in query result?**

Comment: Have you considered using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#picking-up-a-new-property

Comment: @Nirmal but with this I can only add field to all documents and then reindex so that mapping change but I can't only add field to specific documents? For example I can't say give me all documents which has field A == 'x' and field B == 'y' and add flag 'foo' to them instead I can only add flag 'foo' to all documents or more precisely to documents and add they can have additional field? maybe I didn't understand it correctly?

Comment: Not sure i understand the question then , did you meant one update might change document - so that previous query may now fetch it ( earlier it wouldnt)

Comment: @Nirmal I mean one search query would mark all the files it returns. I search for something and query return 10 of 100 documents so than I search with some other query and it returns 15 of 100 documents and first and second query overlap on 5 documents. Then I can query index by return all documents which were returned by fist, by second or by both query. This means each search query should add one tag/mark/label/... to documents it returns.